# Outbound telnet connection from Docker container refused but works fine on host

Tags: networking, docker, telnet, iptables, tutum

I'm facing a network issue on a node hosted via Tutum to AWS.

I sshed into the node and ran

`telnet localhost 3000`

and it works great. When I `docker exec -it <containerid> bash` into one of my containers and run the same command above and I get this error:

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Can anyone shed some light as to why outbound connections from container to host is not permitted?

Comment: What network stack are your containers using? `localhost` mean **local**. On your host it is the host-local-interface, your containers it is their own host-local-interface. So unless you run your containers with `--net=host` it is a regular behavior since there is no service running on `containers-localhost-ip:3000` but only on `host-localhost-ip:3000` which are different.

Comment: Adding net=host in the tutum configuration fixed the issue. Please post your answer so you get credit :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What network stack are your containers using? `localhost` mean local. On your host it is the host-local-interface, your containers it is their own host-local-interface. So unless you run your containers with `--net=host` it is a regular behavior since there is no service running on `containers-localhost-ip:3000` but only on `host-localhost-ip:3000` which are different.